# textTheme.headline2.copywith gives unconditionally invoked Error Flutter

Tags: flutter

here's my code

```
Text(
          "hello",
          style: Theme.of(context)
              .textTheme
              .headline2
              .copyWith(color: Colors.red),
        )
```

I don't know why but it gives

```
The method 'copyWith' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'.
Try making the call conditional (using '?.') or adding a null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add a `?` before using the copyWith method because the value `.headline2`  can be null.

Use it like this:

```
Text(
      "hello",
      style: Theme.of(context)
          .textTheme
          .headline2
          ?.copyWith(color: Colors.red),
    )
```

Since, the style parameter is nullable it should go through without any error.